# _InterlockedExchangeAdd identifier not found when i use openssl 1.1.1d in my code

Tags: compilation, openssl

see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CM8OuieOmdR2z-8m_d7dsWmwcBGbKZLK 
how to fix? i searched on google ,but no answers.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[_InterlockedExchangeAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockedexchangeadd-intrinsic-functions?view=vs-2019) in a Microsoft Visual C++ intrinsic function.

Your error would indicate that something else is defining this function as not a intrinsic function before the Microsoft windows headers.

I would guess that it's something to do with your MSVC install with a incompatible Windows SDK version installed / setup.

Make sure the openssl library is built with the same compiler version / SDK version setup.

Comment: yes,im sure. but I still don't know how to fix it .I am very confused

Comment: i also found "_InterlockedExchangeAdd" in <intrin.h>,my SDK is compatible.

Comment: It is either something to do with your setup of the setup of the whatever compiled openssl library you are using.  You could try to compile a simple program that uses _InterlockedExchangeAdd and see if you get the same problem.  Then it's your setup, so you will need to change it somehow to try to fix it.  Like uninstall everything and only install what you need (i.e. just visual studio version you are using?)